# Checking for the equivalence of a variable in the alphabet.

Tags: r

If I have a letter string, for example "bat" and I do this:

```
x <- "bat"
y <- substr(x, 1, 1)
```

Now I want to create an if condition where I check if y is the same as any letter in the alphabet and if so store the match somewhere else. So I would be checking to see if "b" is the same as a letter in the alphabet (which it is) and then store the match in some variable z.

Comment: You may be looking for `match` i.e .`z <- match(y, letters)`

Comment: almost, this stored "2" in z

Comment: Right, "b" is the 2nd letter in the alphabet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you after something like this?

```
z=letters[sum(which(y==letters))]
```

Comment: yes! Once I'm able to accept your answer (in a couple minutes) I will

Comment: glad to help.  let me know if it returns any errors or needs troubleshooting.